# i am using TCPDF for generating pdf in my wordpress plugin , but on execution it having error on library Header already sent .

Tags: wordpress, pdf, tcpdf

i am using TCPDF for generating pdf in my wordpress plugin , but on execution it having error on library Header already sent .

how can i resolve this issue it appears on output pdf time ?

Comment: Error is for which file? can you share exact error message?

Comment: it just showing error header already sent  in TCPDF library file tcpdf.php

Comment: Can you check that file and remove space if there is in starting of that file.

Comment: ok let me put that as answer so other also can solution easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment , please go to file `tcpdf.php` and check if there any space at starting of file? , If yes then remove that staring space and save file. It will solve your error.

Mostly wordpress fire error **Header Already Sent** , because of space at beginnig of php file.